# SQL Query -- AVG for Occurrence Across Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, group-by, union

I have a table like the following

| ID_A | ID_B | Avg_Class_Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 16 |
| 3 | 4 | 10 |
| 2 | 3 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 | 9 |

Where ID_A and ID_B represent distinct student ID codes, and AVG_Class_Size represents the average class size of the classes shared between students A and B.

I would like to calculate the average of the "avg_class_size" for each student, regardless of whether they are student "A" or student "B", with results like below:

| ID | AVG |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 9.5 |

Is there a simple way to accomplish this with a SQL query?

Comment: The average for id=4 should be 9.5

Comment: Why would you have a table like this? I can't imagine :-(

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.  And how was the original data generated?  What you really want is probably a minor tweak on that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select with `UNION ALL` all the ids and averages of the students and aggregate:

```
SELECT ID, AVG(Avg_Class_Size) average
FROM (
  SELECT ID_A ID, Avg_Class_Size FROM tablename
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID_B ID, Avg_Class_Size FROM tablename
) t
GROUP BY ID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e0f753af4859a195b720620089350b87).
Results:

| ID | average |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 9.5 |